# Can i invite someone on my LAN to view my screen using Apple Remote Desktop?

Tags: macos, apple-remote-desktop

Im aware i can use Apple Remote Desktop (ARD) to connect to other OSX computers on my LAN as long as they have remote management pre enabled.

But can i invite someone on my LAN to view my screen using ARD, without them having access to my machine the rest of the time, unless if i give them an invite.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using ARD for trusted IT management and something like screens express to invite a share on demand.

- https://edovia.com/en/screens-express/

Comment: This is like TeamViewer for the Mac.  Nice.